# Reading in an ascii 'maze' into a 2d array

Tags: c++, file-io, macos, maze

I'm writing code to read in a 7x15 block of text in a file that will represent a 'maze'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "board.h"  

int main()
{
    char charBoard[7][15];  //the array we will use to scan the maze and modify it
    ifstream loadMaze("maze");  //the fstream we will use to take in a maze
    char temp; //our temperary holder of each char we read in

    for(int i = 0;i < 7; i++)
    {

        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        temp= loadMaze.get();
        charBoard[i][j] = temp;
        cout << charBoard[i][j];  //testing
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

this was my original draft but this didnt work as it kept returning ? for each char it read. 
This is the maze im testing with:

```
  #############
              #
############  #
              #
 ######### ####
 # !       #   
############
```

EDIT:
The cout is printing this:

```
  #############


#
############ 
 #

  #
 ######### 
####
 # !      
 #   
#########
```

Am I not escaping \n's?

I've been coding for a few hours so I think its a simple mistake I'm not catching that's tripping me up right now. Thanks!

Comment: whats the contents of the "maze" file ?

Comment: So you're saying that it always prints out `temp=?`?

Comment: Correct, I've edited the question to show what I'm reading and what it's printing

Comment: That's really weird. It works fine for me. I'm getting a bunch of hashes as a result. Are you sure your maze's path is correct?

Comment: That's strange, it's in the same directory as the rest of the files, shouldn't that work just fine?

Comment: Some of the characters you will get are \n (or \r\n on windows) - you'll need to skip those.

Comment: re: file name. This is certainly the error, I changed the filename to something random and it read the same '?'. Anybody have an idea as to why it's not reading the right file?

Comment: @Keith, The maze will always be 7x15 and won't have \n, so I shouldn't be worried, right?

Comment: It will have \n at the end, you'll have to read it in after your j loop.

Comment: Please don't put `[C++]` in your question name. That's what tags are for.

Comment: @danny z - Was there a reason you undid my title edits?

Comment: Oops, I didn't even see the edit! I just took out the [c++] as per your comment! Sorry about that!

Comment: Ah. Just an edit collision. Note to self: When browsing edits, always look at timestamps.

Comment: If your input file has 7 lines, then it has 7 \ns in it.  You could make your input file one line with 7*15 characters on it, or you could skip \ns when reading (do like Jacob, you know where the \ns will be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an absolute path like "c:\MyMazes\maze".

Throw in a system("cd") to see where the current directory is. If you're having trouble finding the current directory, check out this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory/198099#198099)

Here's the complete code - this should display your entire maze (if possible) and the current directory.

```
 char charBoard[7][15];      //the array we will use to scan the maze and modify it
 system("cd");
     ifstream loadMaze("c:\\MyMazes\\maze");  //the fstream we will use to take in a maze

 if(!loadMaze.fail())
 {
    for(int i = 0;i < 7; i++)
    {
        // Display a new line
        cout<<endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
             //Read the maze character
             loadMaze.get(charBoard[i][j]);
             cout << charBoard[i][j];  //testing
        }
        // Read the newline
        loadMaze.get();
    }
    return 0;
 }
 return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether extraction from file is proper: using `good()` API of `ifstream`

```
for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
{
    if(!loadMaze.good())
    {
        cout << "path incorrect";

    }

    temp= loadMaze.get();


    cout << "temp = " << temp << endl; //testing
    charBoard[i][j] = temp;
    cout << charBoard[i][j];  //testing
}
```

OR

in the beginning itself:

```
ifstream loadMaze("maze"); 
if(!loadMaze.good())
{
  //ERROR
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm indeed getting !good()...but why? Maze is in the same folder as all the files

Comment: Throw in a system("cd") to see where the current directory is

Comment: That's actually not doing anything for me, can you eleborate on system("cd"); ?

Comment: What compiler are you using? That's supposed to print your current working directory.

Comment: You can try by giving the absolute path : something like "c:\maze"

Comment: Looks like current working directory is different. try system("cd"); as suggested by @Jacob

Comment: ok it didn't work for textmate but in xCode it shows me the path

Comment: Are you using VS? Try to put the "maze" into the directoy that contains .vcproj .

Comment: Anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: I thought you found the path?

Comment: ah ok, when I run it in Xcode it hides the file about 7 folders deep and I've found it. But the problem is that now it prints a mess. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

try adding the line

```
if (!loadMaze) throw 1;
```

after the declaration of loadMaze, this will throw an exception if the file isn't there. This is a hack, really you should throw a real error. But it works to test.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file opening failed or not. You can find this out by checking if it's good:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/

If the file opening has failed, then try writing in the absolute path to the file (C:/Documents and Settings/.../maze), to see whether that works. If it does, it's just the file path that's wrong, and you'll have to play with that.