# Current user path in Linux?

Tags: linux, gtk

How can I get the current user path in Linux? It can be either with the GTK+ framework APIs, or plain C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory

Comment: Do you mean the current working directory, the user's home directory, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get home directory use `getenv("HOME")`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean the current directory of the process:

- The plain POSIX C function is `getcwd()`.
- In glib, there's also `g_get_current_dir()`.

Answer (score 3):

[`g_get_home_dir()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-home-dir) from Glib is more cross-platform than `getenv("HOME")`. It also prefers /etc/passwd entries over the HOME variable for various reasons discussed at the [aforementioned link](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-home-dir).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you're wanting the contents of $PATH or the user's current working directory. However to cover both options...

PATH is an environment variable, so you can access this with [`getenv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv), in this instance `getenv("PATH")`, and is defined in `<stdlib.h>`.

The current working directory can be obtained with [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd), and is defined in `<unistd.h>`.