# How do I set the working directory to the "solution directory"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to set the current directory to the solution directory/configuration name. How do I do that? Can I use the global variables somehow?

I am trying to read a file and the current directory changes in the middle of the code. I want to change it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your current directory is changing, you should probably save your working directory at startup in some variable you can access later to set cwd back there. At least this is how I understand your question.

For getting the cwd, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory) might help.

Answer (score 57):

In Visual Studio 2010:

1. Go to the project properties (rigth click on the project name in the Solution Explorer, then Properties on the pop up menu).
2. Then, under Configuration Properties / Debugging, set Working Directory to `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`.

---

Full list of available macros (on learn.microsoft.com) : [Common macros for MSBuild commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties)

Comment: Doesn't work for me in my Visual Studio 2017 15.9.10 - says `The working directory you entered does not exist`. Even if I save it, I get `The working directory does not exist: '...\bin\Debug\$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\'.`

Comment: This answer helped me look for the list of available macros, which I found on learn.microsoft.com : [Common macros for MSBuild commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties). In my case : I was looking for `$(ProjectDir)\ `

Comment: @Jonathan: I have this too -- no macros work here. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the posix subsystem ( `<direct.h>` ) and access the functions

[`_getcwd()/_wgetcwd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx) Gets the current working directory
[`_chdir()/_wchdir()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Sets the current working directory

If you need your code to be cross platform, you can do the following:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#  include <direct.h>
#  define getcwd _getcwd
#  define chdir _chrdir
#else
#  include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

and use `getcwd` and `chdir` (w/o the leading underscore).

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the environment variable `$(SolutionDir)`?

With reference to this thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/b0eb3746-285f-4ec6-9658-154f427cdb80).

Also, hopefully, the version of VS does not matter, but this answer is furnished based on the assumption that the platform is VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

1. **For Visual Studio purposes** (include header, etc) you can use macro like $(ProjectDir) or $(SolutionDir) listed here: [VS macro list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019)
2. To read files in **code of your app** use Windows API function [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) that retrieves path to your **process** directory. Compiled code may live independently of project therefore it make sense to refer path to data files relatively to process (exe).

It seems author of question asks about 2-nd item and others answer to 1-st item.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GetCurrentDirectory` to have a full path and roll back to where you want to stay with standard C++ string API. Here is my sample code for your reference.

```
int main() {
    TCHAR current_dir_wc[MAIN_FN_LEN_LIMIT];
    char  current_dir[MAIN_FN_LEN_LIMIT];
    char  project_dir[MAIN_FN_LEN_LIMIT];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAIN_FN_LEN_LIMIT, current_dir_wc); 
    sprintf(current_dir, "%s\\", wc2str(current_dir_wc).c_str());
    strncpy(project_dir, (const char*)current_dir, (strstr((const char*)current_dir, "UR_VS_SOLUTION_NAME")-current_dir+strlen("UR_VS_SOLUTION_NAME\\")));
    printf("[%s]Current DIR:%s\n", __func__, current_dir);
    printf("[%s]Project DIR:%s\n", __func__, project_dir);
}
```