# How do you include initial_path() from Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, include

I installed Boost and have the code `#include <boost/initial_path.hpp>` in my source and it still says "No such file or directory". I've never included an external library before, how do I do this?

Why does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108650/replacement-for-deprecated-boost-filesystem-initial-path) `claim initial_path()` is deprecated?

Comment: What compiler tools are you using

Comment: The question you've linked to has a link from Boost docs stating it is deprecated, and the selected answer explains that it was probably done because the functionality is trivial for you to implement yourself. That should answer your question of why the file no longer exists. I can confirm that `initial_path.hpp` header doesn't exist in 1.50.0

Comment: I was under the impression that Boost was system independent. How can I get the execution directory in a system independent way?

Comment: That looks like a great question to ask on Stack Overflow, Celeritas. If it hasn't already been asked, please post it as a new question instead of burying it in a comment.

Comment: I found a similar question here. Is the accepted answer actually platform independent? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory According to Thorsten79 there is not way without an external Library like Boost but then the question I mentioned earlier said that `initial_path()` is deprecated. (btw @RobKennedy I can't tell if your being serious or sarcastic)

Comment: I'm being completely serious. Comments are not the place to ask new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your command line:

```
-Ic:/your_boost_directory
```

or look how to specify include paths in the docs for your compiler.