# Finding the directory where file is being executed from?

Tags: c++, file, boost, filesystems, filenames

I want to call `opendir()` with the argument of the directory the program is being run from. If possible it will be a platform independent way. I'm confused because the accepted answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory) doesn't look to be platform independent. Other answers say use Boost but a reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108650/replacement-for-deprecated-boost-filesystem-initial-path) states `initial_path()` is deprecated. If it can't be done in a platform independent the target is Windows.

Comment: Have you tried `opendir(.)` with the literal dot '.' for the current working directory?

Comment: You can't have a *totally* platform independent path handling, simply beause not all platforms have paths. :-)

Comment: The second question you link to has the answer: Get the current directory when your program starts, and remember it for later when you need it. A comment confirms that Boost's `current_path` can help you with the first part of that task. The first question's accepted answer is simply another implementation of `current_path`; the answer just neglects to point out that you should call it early in your program and then refer to the saved result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initial_path()` is deprecated, but it effectively called `current_path()` at the beginning of the program for you and then returned that result on any subsequent calls. So all you need to do is call `current_path()` at the beginning of your program and store it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is cross platform, and tells you the program's current working directory.

char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);

This is a posix function, and should be supported on Linux, OsX and Windows. Read about it here:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd

Comment: getcwd is supported on Windows, but is called _getcwd

Comment: size_t is generally the size of a register on most platforms. size_t will work on linux and OsX. Use DWORD on Windows.

Comment: @Celeritas: You pass the size of `buf` as the second parameter so that it does over-run the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Approximately the same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory).

You can also get help from here: [Makefile Tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)

You can use these commands as well

```
initial_path()
current_path()
```