# Win API Local File Reference c++

Tags: c++, file, io

I am trying to hard code into C++ program to look for config.ini in the same directory as the executable, without knowing the complete path to the file.  I am trying to find a way to make a local reference to the executable.

Basically load ("./config.ini")
without doing

("C:\foo\bar\config.ini")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`GetModuleFilename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows (pass NULL to get filename of current executable).  Otherwise, call [`boost::filesystem::initial_path()`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#initial_path) early in the program (see Boost docs in link for the reason to do this early).  That should cover most of the situations.

**Edit**

Brain malfunction.  We always start our programs from the executable's directory, so the `boost::initial_path()` thing works, but it won't work so well if you start the program from another direcory.  Sorry for the confusion on that.  On Windows, though, I'd get the path from `GetModuleFilename` and use `boost::path` to manipulate the result.

Comment: `GetModuleFilename` has the correct behavior, but `initial_path()` is not useful here since it is trivial to start a process with a CWD different than the directory containing the executable.

Comment: Must have been editing to that effect when you were writing this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really any guaranteed portable way of doing this, but I like to use this code because it works in the vast majority of cases (unless symlinks or other magic is involved):

```
boost::filesystem::current_path(boost::filesystem::path(argv[0]).remove_filename());
```

If you are willing to use platform specific code look at `GetModuleFileName` on Windows and a mix of `getpid`, reading from `/proc` and `readlink` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, this will get the directory containing the excutable as a c++  string:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

string ExePath() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    return string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos);
}
```

You can then just tag the name of your config file on the end.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows:

```
#include <direct.h>

char cur_path[FILENAME_MAX];

if (!_getcwd(cur_path, sizeof(cur_path)))
{
    // deal with error
}

cur_path[sizeof(cur_path) - 1] = '/0'; // adding \0 at the end of the string

printf("Current dir: %s", cur_path);
```

A platform-agnostic solution was discussed here:

[How do I get the directory that a program is running from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/143174/176769)

Comment: He's not asking how to get the current working directory, but how to get the directory of the executable.

Comment: The OP is going to hardcode this checking into his application. Whenever the application is executed, _getcwd() will return the current directory, which is where config.ini is located.