# Is there a way for a C binary code to figure out where it is stored?

Tags: directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: How to obtain the full path of current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory)

It is simple to figure out the directory which a bash script resides in, but I'm wondering if it is true for a c binary code.

Comment: What do you mean with the qualifier "binary"? If you want the directory your code is executing in it rather straightforward. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory

Comment: Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe