# Eclipse cannot read file when using freopen or fopen CPP

Tags: c++, eclipse

I try to use freopen ("inputString.txt","r",stdin); to send
input to standard input.If I run program in eclipse the output is
xxx
but if I run program directly (run *.exe after compile without eclipse)
the output is goodxxx

The text file is in the same directory of *.exe in eclipse project.
How can I fix this.
Here is some of my sourcecode.

```
 int main() {
int debug = 1,width,height;
char s[1000];
freopen ("inputString.txt","r",stdin);

s[0]='x';
scanf("%s",s);
printf("%s",s);
printf("xxx")for(;;);;

return 0;}
```

inputString.txt contain

good

Comment: If this is C++, why not use a `istream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put file in the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Check the current directory in your launch configuration, make sure it's what you expect. You can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory) to get and print the current directory from within your program to see where you are.

Comment: My current directory is true but it still wrong if run via eclipse

Answer (score 0):

```
test
|___Binaries
|___Included
|___src
    |__test.cpp
    |__input.txt
|___Debug
|___Release
```

If this is your Eclipse C++ project structure, then to access contents of file **input.txt** in **test.cpp** you need to write

```
freopen("src/input.txt", "r", stdin);
```

"test" is the root dir