# Issue with getcwd C++

Tags: c++

I wanted to obtain the `PATH of Current Working Directory` in `C++` program. It should run for `Windows`, `Sun Solaris`, `UNIX`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from) to be my answer. But our compiler is giving error that it cannot find the file `unistd.h`. I am compiling in Windows. I have used the exact same code as mentioned in the correct answer. What is the problem here?

Plus my boss is questioning the working of this code. I have commented the UNIX lines & the program is running fine in Windows. Even he does not know how this code is working. Can anybody please explain this code to me please?
Thank You.

Comment: Read the linked answer again, and ask yourself: does your Windows build define the WINDOWS symbol so that the right includes are used? `unistd.h` doesn't exist on Windows and the code is fairly explicit about not wanting to include it, it uses `_getcwd` from direct.h instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<unistd.h>` is not supposed to be found on Windows. The file to be included in Windows according to [How do I get the directory that a program is running from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from) is `<direct.h>`. Check your preprocessor macros.

Comment: actually I have added them in a function where i want the path.
Is it ok? or should add it globally?

Comment: @CAD_coding You can't include headers in a function, so what exactly are you doing? The code assumes `WINDOWS` is defined when compiling under Windows, so check your preprocessor variable to make sure it is defined there.

Comment: The lines starting from `#ifdef` till the `#endif` line should be added at the top, not in the function

Comment: Works like a charm on Windows!