# How does relative paths in codeblocks work?

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I am using code blocks and set the search directory as a relative path, But my program won't find the libs unless the program is launched from within code blocks.

Does anyone know how relative paths in code blocks work when the program is launched outside of code blocks?

Is there a way to make the path relative to the executable's directory?

OS: Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative paths are resolved based on the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), i.e. where you launch the program from.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from) for more discussion on this and how to get the directory containing the running program.

Comment: well, it dont seem to work that way either. i specify "Lib" in search directory for linker. and i got a folder named "Lib" in the same folder containing my exe. but i can still not run it by double clicking on it from explorer.

Comment: I will accept this answer as it is correct. although it didn't work for me i found a way to workaround that.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: i just stuffed my exe in the lib folder and made an shortcut. Not really a solution but it does make it easier to launch the exe without having to look trough a bounch of dll's, which was all i needed. still wierd that it dident work the normal way.