# Get the original location where the program is called

Tags: c, windows, unistd.h, getcwd

Is there any way to know the directory where the program is originally spawned in C? I want my program to know where it is located in the computer. I already tried using `_getcwd()` in `direct.h`. I also tried `getcwd()` using `unistd.h`. But here's the problem. If I added a PATH to my program's directory, the functions `_getcwd()` and `getcwd()` path will return the path where I called the program. So if I ran the program in dekstop, it will return the path of the desktop instead. I already tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145309/5794981) method but it doesn't fix the problem. It returns the value of the calling path. I would like to know what function to use to know the path of the program and not the path that the program is called.
What function should I use?

Comment: Already tried those method earlier. It's returning the path of where it is called and not the original path of the program being called.

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory is of no use whatsoever. There is no connection between an executable image's location in the filesystem and the current working directory, other than coincidental.

You can retrieve the fully qualified path to the executable by calling [_get_wpgmptr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2zbk054.aspx) (a Microsoft-specific extension to the CRT that ships with Visual Studio) or [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) (passing `NULL` for *hModule*), and extract the path by calling [PathRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx) (or [PathCchRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092.aspx) for Windows 8 and above).

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. What library does `_get_wpgmptr()` appears? Already included `stdlib.h` and `windows.h` but the compiler says: `undefined reference to ' _get_wpgmptr'`.

Comment: @BryanJames: `_get_wpgmptr()` is part of Visual Studio's CRT implementation, so you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` **and** use Visual Studio (or the Microsoft Compiler). If you are using a different compiler, you can use the Windows API call `GetModuleFileName` instead.