# Open CMD in the directory where my program is

Tags: c++, windows, command-line

I have a piece of software written in c++, that has to call command line and execute 2 simple commands. The problem is, they need to be executed in the main directory of my program (folder where exe file is). How can I make sure, that they will execute in this directory, if it can be different on PCs (for example "Program Files" or "Program Files(x86)").

Comment: Posible dupliacte: [get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from)

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can use the [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI, which will return you the path of the exe that you can `cd` to and execute your commands.