# C++ Can't Open&Read File

Tags: c++, file

I can't open the file in c++. I saw a lot of page that asked same question but i can't figured it out. I opened new project for just open the file (As you can see). -I also tryed it with mingw but nothing changed. I try to put the file everywhere in the folder. Please help.

```
string sayi;    
ifstream oku("sayilar.txt");
if (oku.is_open())
{
    cout << "Opened";
}
else
{
    cout << "Can't opened";
}
int x; cin >> x;
```

Comment: What's your programs working directory? Is it the same where `sayilar.txt` lives?

Comment: Typically when you do not specify the exact file location it needs to sit next to the exe file or in the directory where the source code is.

Comment: use the full path of file instead. eg: `"E:/User/desktop/sayilar.txt"`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you're asking about my document structure as i understand simply, My file in the folder (Desktop/MyProject near by Project.sln) and also i copyied it in Desktop/Project/Project near by main.cpp 
But; if you're asking something complex (about working directory) How can i check it?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes i tryed to put the txt file near sln-cpp-exe. There were 3 sayilar.txt in solution folder on my last try

Comment: @FurkanAyık http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from

Comment: @Raindrop7 But i must be able to send the project someone else. It must be worked like this. (I know it can be work like this)

Comment: The [`_getcwd` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx) will tell you where the program is going to look for your file. [Be warned that the working directory moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: Negative votes -_-  I've been trying to fix this for 2 days. I could found no solution in web, so i don't know what that negative votes for. But i got my advice. I'll keep try. Thanks everyone

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for the text file?

Comment: @AlessandroScarlatti No sir. I'm at work now but if you could say how to do it i can check it after work

Comment: add the full path of file instead of the file's name

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the real problem but i think it is about my OS settings (Win10). When i write "sayilar.txt.txt" instead of "sayilar.txt" **it works.**
I've tryed to uncheck "hide extensions of known file types" setting but it stil doesn't work. (There was no answer about that problem in StackOverflow, for that negative voters) So i'll work with "sayilar.txt.txt". Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your file name so you are hiding the file extension then the first `.txt` is considered to be a part of file name not extension so if you show file extension then you'll get your file `sayilar.txt.txt` so try to rename it correctly so:

- either hide file extensions and rename the file to `sayilar` only without adding `.txt` because it is hidden.
- or show file extensions and then rename the file to `sayilar.txt` so there's no extra extension.
- if the problem persists then delete file and create a text file named `sayilar` : right click in your current folder or in any void place in the desktop -> New -> Text Document. enter the name `sayilar`.

I wish this will figure out your problem.

Comment: Sir i figured it out somehow. Like i said it was a win10 settings problem. (Using mingw as compiler is an option) Thank you for your answer. I hope it will be helpful someone who will come here. Regards.