# readlink sets errno to ENOENT

Tags: c++, linux, readlink

I'm an inexperienced Linux programmer and am trying to learn to use `readlink()` based on this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from).

My call to `readlink()` returns -1 and sets `errno` to 2 (`ENOENT`).

**The code:**

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char szTmp[100];
  snprintf(szTmp, 100, "proc/%d/exe", getpid());
  std::cout << "szTmp is " << szTmp << std::endl;
  char executingFolder[500];
  errno = 0;
  int bytes = std::min(readlink(szTmp, executingFolder, 500), (ssize_t)499);

  if (bytes > 0)
  {
    executingFolder[bytes] = '\0';
  }

  std::cout << "bytes is " << bytes << std::endl;
  std::cout << "errno is " << errno;
  if (ENOENT == errno)
  {
    std::cout << " ENOENT";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Executing folder is \"" << executingFolder << "\"" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**The output:**

(An example from one iteration since pid changes)

```
szTmp is proc/22272/exe
bytes is -1
errno is 2 ENOENT
Executing folder is ""
```

**Things I have tried:**

- After compilation: `sudo ./a.out` (thinking that directory access was restricted because of lack of permission). Result: unchanged behavior from `./a.out`
- SIGINT the program during execution, and verified that `/proc/<pid>/exe` exists. Result: it consistently exists for each run of the program.
- Verified that the value of the target link is well within 499 chars.

Can someone please help identify the problem? Having read the `readlink` man page and online descriptions, and the noted StackOverflow article, I am still unclear what is wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proc/1234/exe` is a relative path.

I think you want `/proc/%d/exe`, which is an absolute path, and correctly refers to the `/proc` directory.

---

Secondly, because `readlink()` will truncate the result in case the buffer is too small, you should consider the case where the return value is `== bufsiz` to be  an error, as truncation may have happened. You can't know.

---

Also, *"Executing folder"* is not what `/proc/<pid>/exe` gives you. `/proc/<pid>/exe` is a symlink to the currently running executable (file), not a directory.

Comment: I beat you to it!

Comment: Thank you, I understand your explanation and my error now.

Comment: @KeithThompson You did indeed, by about 30 seconds, but I needed to bring up the other two errors.

Answer (score 1):

`proc/22272/exe` is a relative path name. It resolves to the file `exe`, in the directory `22272`, in the directory `proc`, in your *current* directory. Unless your current directory is `/`, that's unlikely to exist.

You want an *absolute* path name, starting with `/`, in this case `/proc/22272/exe`.

Change this:

```
snprintf(szTmp, 100, "proc/%d/exe", getpid());
```

to this:

```
snprintf(szTmp, 100, "/proc/%d/exe", getpid());
```

But before you fix your program, you might try this:

```
( cd / ; ~/a.out )
```

(assuming `a.out` is in your home directory).

Comment: Thank you also. I hate to choose between two correct and generous answers from the very same minute (SO only gives minute resolution(?)). But I'll upvote both your answers.