# ifstream does not open a file in the next iteration

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I have two similar methods that open a file identically, but process them and return values a bit differently, yet while the first method does that successfully, the second method, which is called after the first one, fails.

I have tried changing the path to this file, its extension, but I think I miss some important knowledge about ifstream.

```cpp
vector<User> Database::createUserDatabase()
{   
    vector<User> users;

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(pathToFile, ios::in);

    //Some file processing

    inputFile.close();
    return users;
}
```

And that works perfectly, while

```cpp
vector<User> Database::createBookDatabase()
{   
    vector<Book> books;

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(pathToFile, ios::in);

    //Some file processing

    inputFile.close();
    return books;
}
```

fails to end whenever I check if the file has been opened or not using

```cpp
inputFile.is_open()
```

These functions are defined in class files Database.cpp, User.cpp, Book.cpp, which are correctly linked to the main.cpp with the following content:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include "../lib/Book.h"
#include "../lib/User.h"
#include "../lib/Database.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    Database userDatabase("../database/users.txt", "users");
    Database bookDatabase("../database/lmsdb.txt", "books");

    vector<User> users = userDatabase.createUserDatabase();
    vector<Book> books = bookDatabase.createBookDatabase();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are my [Project directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjOJy.png)

Using gdb debugger, I have confirmed that the file is not being opened at all. I assume that I did not close the files properly, but I have a little knowledge of C++ yet (been learning it for only a week or so).

Looking forward to see what you can suggest reading/researching, yet I really would like to see a straightforward solution to this problem.

Comment: "vector<User> Database::createBookDatabase()" has a bug. Should be "vector<Book> Database::createBookDatabase()". Does this compile?

Comment: @ArminMontigny it is just a typo, the code is correct on my machine. The issue is in the improper path to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume that I did not close the files properly, [..]

Yes, but that probably isn't the cause of the issue. The C++ way is to not close them explicitly. Due to [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), the `ifstream` will close itself once it goes out of scope (i.e. when the enclosing function terminates).

There are many reasons why a file could fail to open, including:

- It doesn't exist.
- Trying to open a read-only file in write mode.
- The file is in use by another process. (Maybe you have it opened in an editor?)
- Insufficient privileges (e.g. due to the file being protected).

Comment: Thanks, I have found the way to get it to work. Instead of stating the relative path to the files, I have entered a full path as follows: `D:\\Work\\Projects\\ENG 101 Final Project\\database\\users.txt`, and that works. Could you explain why?

Comment: I'm not sure, unless the working directory isn't where you think it is, both should be equivalent. However, then your other function wouldn't work either... [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from) shows how to retrieve the working directory. You could verify it using that.