# find the pwd variable of the current process that called my system call

Tags: c, linux

i hooked the `sys_execve` because i need to build simple monitor that prints when files executes ,but the problem is when someone run a program like this

```
./exefilename
```

it prints in the log file only the name of the file and not the full path,
also in this case my monitor will print

```
./exefilename
```

instead of the full path name so i was wondering if there is any way to find what the `pwd` of the bash hat called the `execve` system call? .
this is my code of the monitor

```
static asmlinkage long our_execl(const char __user * filename,
            const char __user * const __user * argv,
            const char __user * const __user * envp) {

   strncpy_from_user(buf, filename, 255);
    buf[255] = '\0';

    printk("%s\n",buff);
    return_orginal(filename,argv,envp)//call the real sys_execve
```

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from help?

Comment: See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6-rc1/source/fs/proc/base.c#L185