# How to find the path where the file app is running

Tags: c++

i want to find where the app that i am running in which folder is, like detect the path. I want to do this because i want to run some files that are in the folder with the program, so you can open the files in the path that you want and it would work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`std::filesystem::current_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the directory that a program is running from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get path of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable)