# How read .txt file in c++ program

Tags: c++

How to read the txt file in the same directory when you run the exe file in the directory set in PATH .

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Start" << endl;
    for (int index = 1; index < argc; index++)
        cout << argv[index] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    ifstream readFile("test.txt");
    if (readFile.is_open())
    {
        string str;
        for (; !readFile.eof();)
        {
            readFile >> str;
            cout << str << endl;
        }

        readFile.close();
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "faile open file" << endl;
    }

    cout << "End" << endl;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Other than `for (; !readFile.eof();` ([explanation of why that's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)), this doesn't look bad. What's the problem you've encountered?

Comment: When debugging in Visual Studio the default working directory is  the folder containing the project file that way both Release and Debug configurations have the same folder as the default. if you click on the file in the file explorer it will default to the folder where the executable is in. You can change this default in the Debugger settings of your project.

Comment: replace `cout << "faile open file" << endl;` by something like `perror("failed open file");` to see the reason, but probably your program cannot find the file because you are not in the right directory

Comment: @user4581301 the problem is the file cannot be open (first picture)

Comment: @drescherjm the second picture indicates the program was started by hand in a terminal no ?

Comment: I think that was just to show the file location not how it was started because it would have worked if the user clicked on the executable.

Comment: @drescherjm the second picture show the program started with its 2 args then traces. But waiting for OP remarks ;-)

Comment: Is that powershell? Not exactly sure what the OP is running the program inside there.

Comment: Actually I didn't know that. Can't see the images.

Comment: @user4581301 that is strange, refresh page ( I edited the question to show pictures rather than links 11 mins ago)

Comment: One of the more recent answers here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from  You will need to get the full path of the currently executable and then extract the directory from that to prepend to your file path, or once you have the directory you want to use change the current working directory to be there and use relative paths.

Comment: @bruno I know they're there. I know you edited the question to make them visible. I've just got something blocking them. Have to look into that later.

Comment: I'm making a CLI program. This program receives commands from the user and imports something from the txt file. I execute program with powershell at release directory. No problem.(I move release directory) But after setting  release directory at Windows environment variable(PATH), execute this program at powershell can't read file. Why is that?